# Beego: How do I use If-else conditions in templates?

Tags: go, beego

How do I use conditions in beego's templating system?
Or is it just expected that we use this for templating instead?

https://github.com/ipfans/beego-pongo2.v2

I'd like to try my best first to do this Beego's way before latching something else on here. I mean....surely conditional rendering was thought of when creating beego's stock templating system right?

While we're at it what about looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Beego Template Parsing](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md) docs:

> Beego uses Go’s builtin package [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) as the template parser.

[Beego WebIM Sample](https://github.com/beego/samples/blob/c9a2f4eabafd5260be184159a63aa279e5cf5093/WebIM/views/base/head.html#L10):

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
{{if .IsLongPolling}}
<script src="/static/js/longpolling.js"></script>
{{else}}
<script src="/static/js/websocket.js"></script>
{{end}}
```